# ReadKey in Console Application c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to do something when user presses for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> keys, how can I do it? I tried this but didn't work:

```
if ((ConsoleKey.G && ConsoleModifiers.Control)!=0) Console.WriteLine("test");
```

Comment: Why do you specify A and Control if you want Alt and G?

Comment: It's G it was mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Console.ReadKey` to retrieve a `ConsoleKeyInfo`.

Read up on that method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: And how do i compare it in if?

Comment: @rNuǝɹɐ there are examples at that post.

Answer (score 4):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.G && keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Alt)
  Console.WriteLine("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `Console.ReadKey()`?

For example, you can do the following :

```
Console.WriteLine("Please press Alt+G: ");
ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
```

You can then check for the *Alt* modifier in info. There's a fairly relative case from the Microsoft page for `Console.ReadKey` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx